# How to use order by and group by together in mysql?

Tags: sql-order-by

I have two tables in one of my website, one table is to hold author information (id,name,image, type) the other one is to store articles(id, author_id, title, contents, date). Author my have more than one articles. I want in my sql generate a list of articles linked with the author table sorted by the newest article but for each author I want to display only one article which is the newest one. Any one can have an idea about this please help ...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select 
    a.* 
from 
    article as a 
WHERE 
    a.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM article GROUP BY author_id);
```

If you want the author details also try

```
select 
    a.*,au.name,au.image  
from 
    article as a, 
    autor as au 
WHERE 
    a.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM article GROUP BY author_id)
AND 
    a.author_id = au.id;
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8198b/19

Comment: thanks alot for this great help , I wrote the sql but was fine but is very slow what do you think?

Comment: do you have indexing in you fields, please try indexing the id, author_id field in article table and id of author table

Comment: This answer assumes that the id values of the articles go in the same order as the date values.  This isn't necessarily the case.  To answer the question correctly, you really need to look for the latest article date for each author, not the highest article id.

Answer (score 1):

The right query for this is the following.

```
select * from article a
where a.date >= all (select b.date from article b where a.author_id = b.author_id)
```

If this is too slow, then you could try an index by `(author_id, date)` on the `article` table.  Note that the order of the columns in the index is important.  `author_id` has to be first.

Comment: thanks a lot but what about author information I want to join this query with author information ? how can I do that ? and what do you mean by index the IDS , how can I do this ??

Comment: You can join to the author in the `from` clause, just like you would for any other query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM author, article WHERE author.id=article.author_id order by date DESC) 
        tab group by id
```

This is correct query for get latest article by author.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it does not work can yo please double check the sql ?